# URL Rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

To change the URL `/mobiles.php?id=5` to `/mobiles/5`

The content of .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /mobiles/$1 ^/mobiles.php?id=([0-9]+)$
```

But still it is showing `/mobiles.php?id=5` in the address bar. Please help. Is there anything else needs to be added in the `.htaccess` file?

Note:

1. mod_rewrite module is enabled
2. I have restarted Apache server after making changes to the .htaccess
   file
3. .htaccess file is in htdocs folder of Apache.
4. I am using Windows + PHP + Apache + MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^mobiles/([0-9]+)$ mobiles.php?id=$1&rew [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^mobiles.php$ /mobiles/%1? [R,L]
```

If you see this line:

`RewriteRule ^mobiles/([0-9]+)$ mobiles.php?id=$1&rew [L]`

I have added `rew` variable in the query string to prevent Apache to fall in an infinite loop

When Apache execute this line:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$`

Is to make sure that url has not been rewritten for Apache

Comment: Thanks alot! This works for me. But when the page is displaying, all the CSS and Javascript files are not included and page layout is disturbed. Can you pls suggest on this?

Comment: you need to add the [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag in your html page

Comment: One more help! I want to fetch some information from the database and want to display in the URL (for example instead of displaying `id` for a mobile, I want to display its corresponding title like `mobiles/blackberry-9000/`). You know how to do it? Any website link/tutorial that can help?

Comment: that's called [url slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29) you can googling it for more info

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is that the old url stays in the address bar, and you want this **not** to happen, try adding an `[R]` at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^/mobiles.php?id=([0-9]+)$ /mobiles/$1 [R]
```

Did you actually see the correct page?

By the way, the rewrite rules generally go the other way.  I would be expecting to see something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/mobiles/([0-9]+)$ /mobiles.php?id=$1
```

Is your concern one of making sure a URL with query parameters does not show up in the address bar?

Comment: Yes my concern is that old URL stays in address bar. I tried adding [R] then also it is not changing. Yes I am seeing the correct page.

Comment: Interesting, `[R]` is supposed to do a complete redirect.  It always updates the address bar for me.  Sorry it did not work for you.

Comment: Which server and OS you are using?

Comment: Apache with mod_rewrite on both MacOSX and Linux.  A sample rewrite rule of mine is `RewriteRule ^notes/(\w+)$ notes/$1/ [R]`.  This has the effect of adding a slash at the end of the URL.  If you enter `http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/charenc` (note **no trailing slash**) into the address bar, you will see a slash added.  That is because of the `[R]` in the rewrite rule.

Comment: Will it work on my local machine? I am testing this on my own machine i.e. my URL is like `http://localhost/<something>/mobiles.php?id=5`

Comment: I run apache locally and the rewriting with redirection works for me with localhost urls as well. Do _other_ rewrite rules work?

Comment: I checked only this rewriting rule and it is not working. What do you mean by rewriting and redirection? What I doing above is rewriting only...right?

Comment: Any url can be rewritten, but the `[R]` performs redirection. With redirection the browser address bar should be changed to reflect the url to which the redirect occurs. For information, search for "external redirect" on [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want

- Internally redirect `/mobiles/5` to `/mobiles.php?id=5`
- Also redirect the browser TO `/mobiles/5` if a user navigates to `/mobiles.php?id=5`

For this you need 2 rules one to internally rewrite the URL for 1st case and 2nd for browser redirection.

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# for internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^/?mobiles/([0-9]+)/?$ /mobiles.php?id=$1 [L]

# for browser redirect
RewriteRule ^/?mobiles\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /mobiles/$1/ [R,L]
```

Comment: @iSumitG Can you please explain how it is not working. It might help me in determining the problem and providing you with a working solution

Comment: Hi Danishgoel! This does not work. URL is not changing. It still contains the `.php` and `id=5`. Also when I enter `/mobiles/5` in address bar then it shows "No such page on server". However, I just accepted one answer for this question. That one is working for me. I don't know why that one is working fine but yours not working for me. Let me know if any more details required :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the opposite, should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/something/mobiles/([0-9]+)$ /something/mobiles.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Tried changing also. No change in the URL. It stays as it is.

Comment: @iSumitG Instead of inputing `/mobiles?id=1`, you can just input `/mobiles/1`, this is what this rewriterule for.

Comment: but when I type `/mobiles/1` into the address bar, it is showing `Not Found on server` error

Comment: @iSumitG you have something before /mobiles, so add it will work.